# Bulk Insert parameterized stored proc SQL 15

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I'm sure to be missing something silly, but I can't seem to figure it out after many hours.

Created a stored proc in SQL 15 that looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkLoad] 
    @BulkInsertFromFile varchar(255) = null, 
    @MaxNumberOfFileErrors int = 0
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @parameterDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @parameterDefinition = N'@a varchar, @b int, @c varchar, @d varchar, @e int'
SET @statement = '
    BULK INSERT CombinedRawData
    FROM @a
    WITH (
            FIRSTROW=@b,
            FIELDTERMINATOR=@c,
            ROWTERMINATOR=@d,
            MAXERRORS=@e)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql  @statement, @parameterDefinition, @BulkInsertFromFile, 2, ',', '\n', @MaxNumberOfFileErrors
```

Stored proc is created without errors. However, execution using

```
EXEC BulkLoad N'C:\Temp\Data.txt',5
```

I receive the error message:
Incorrect syntax near '@a'.

Any assistance or pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Gene

Comment: You don't need to create a string to execute statements that accept parameters. Creating that string *won't* force them to accept parameters either. If `FROM` doesn't accept parameters outside a string, it won't accept them inside that string either

Comment: Why are you using this stored procedure instead of directly calling `BULK INSERT`? The only thing it does is hard-code the table name. Where do you call it from? Client code? Some other stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkLoad] 
    @BulkInsertFromFile varchar(255) = null, 
    @MaxNumberOfFileErrors int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @parameterDefinition NVARCHAR(4000)

    --check if file exists..better use something else than xp_fileexist
    declare @fileexists int;
    exec xp_fileexist @BulkInsertFromFile, @fileexists output;

    if isnull(@fileexists, 0) <> 1
    begin
        raiserror('file does not exist', 16, 1);
        return;
    end

    select @BulkInsertFromFile = replace(@BulkInsertFromFile, '''', '''''');


    declare @a varchar(5), 
            @b int = 2, 
            @c varchar(5) = ',', 
            @d varchar(5) = '\n', 
            @e int = case when isnull(@MaxNumberOfFileErrors, 0) <= 0 then 0 else @MaxNumberOfFileErrors end;


    SET @statement = N'
        BULK INSERT CombinedRawData
        FROM ''' + @BulkInsertFromFile + N'''
        WITH (
                FIRSTROW= ' + cast(@b as nvarchar(5)) + N',
                FIELDTERMINATOR=''' + @c + N''',
                ROWTERMINATOR=''' + @d + N''',
                MAXERRORS=' + cast(@e as nvarchar(15)) + N'
            )';

    --print @statement
    exec (@statement);
END
```

Comment: Thank you lptr! Not only does your code do the job, it offers additional benefits of verifying the file exists and checking the file error int is not null. The concise answer is much appreciated. Cheers, Gene